# "Run Keyword If" and setting a variable

Tags: variables, if-statement, conditional-statements, robotframework

The following code doesn't work.
I want to set a variable if a condition is true.

```
    Run Keyword If    ${MAC} == 110299160221421    ${device_serial}=    set variable    ${device_serial_1}
```

I get the error:

```
No keyword with name '=' found
```

This is working but doesn't change a variable.

```
    Run Keyword If    ${MAC} == 110299160221421    Log to console    111
```

Comment: does the first variant works without if?

Comment: no, this doesn't work

Comment: I'm not familiar with robotframework, but looks like device_serial is a readonly system variable.

Comment: @nicolay.anykienko: robot has no notion of "readonly system variables".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Run keyword if` returns the result of the keyword that you're running. So, like with any other keyword, you put a variable in the first column if you want to save the value:

```
${device_serial}=  run keyword if  ${MAC} == 110299160221421  
...    set variable    ${device_serial_1}
```

I this specific case you might want to use [Set Variable If](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If) instead of Run Keyword If

```
${device_serial}=  set variable if  ${MAC} == 110299160221421
...    ${device_serial_1}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked with this code:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Run Keyword If    ${MAC} == 110299160221421    myKeyword    

*** Keywords ***
myKeyword
    ${device_serial}=    set variable    ${device_serial_1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this problem is, so you can use else if(s) and else at the end:

```
${device_serial}=    Set Variable If    ${MAC} == 110299160221421    ${device_serial_1}
...    ${MAC} == 12345678    set variable    ${device_serial_2}    ${device_serial_general}
```